# SQL Subquery with OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following schema:

```
+--------+---------+
|Name    |    Brand|
+--------+---------|
|John    |   Iphone|
|John    |  Samsung|
|Carl    |   Xiaomi|
|Natan   |   Iphone|
|Julie   |  Samsung|
+--------+---------+
```

In my result I need to return the names which frame in these 2 scenarios:

1- Have **only Iphone**

OR

2 - Have a **exclusive combination of Iphone and Samsung**; This way, I need this output:

```
+--------+
|Name    |
+--------+
|John    |
|Natan   |
+--------+
```

This is what I tried, but with no success:

```
select name
from schema
where brand = 'Iphone' or
brand in 
    (select brand
    from schema
    where brand = 'Iphone' and brand = 'Samsung')
```

Comment: what if someone have iphone and xiaomi ? it should be inside the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using  union between the iphone olny and the pair iphone-samsung

```
    select name
    from schema
    where brand = 'Iphone' 
    union 
    select name 
    from schema
    where brand in  ('Iphone' , 'Samsung') 
    group by name
    having count(distinct brand) = 2
```

Comment: also it should be something to filter only Iphone users. currently it gets all iphone users. also it creates duplicates if someone have iphone and samsung

Comment: select union don't return duplicate ...  you comment is not clear ..

Comment: What if some user has both Iphone and Xiaomi?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If you want the names to `only have Iphone` or  a combination of `combination of Iphone and Samsung`:

Try:

```
SELECT distinct name
FROM my_table
WHERE Brand IN (
               SELECT Brand
               FROM my_table
               WHERE brand='Iphone'
               GROUP BY Brand
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                )
 OR   name in ( SELECT name
                FROM my_table
                WHERE brand in ('Iphone','Samsung')
                GROUP BY name
                 HAVING COUNT(brand)=2 
              ) 
;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/150

If you need names that at least have `Iphone` or a combination of `Samsung and Iphone`   use:

```
 select distinct name
 from my_table
 where brand = 'Iphone' or name in ( SELECT name
                                    FROM my_table
                                    WHERE brand in ('Iphone','Samsung')
                                    GROUP BY name
                                    HAVING COUNT(brand)=2 ) ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/148

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT brand ORDER BY brand) AS brands
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
HAVING brands IN ('Iphone', 'Iphone,Samsung');
```